# Echo values to table based on date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am working io creating a staff app to keep track of the number of actual employees and the number needed for each month for each department. I want to keep track for the next 12 months from whenever the app is run. I have the following table:

```
id | group_id | group_name         | needed | actual
1  | 1        | Apartments         | 10     | 9
2  | 2        | Apartments Spanish | 12     | 8
```

My code so far:

```
<?php
    $getgroups = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `su_cal_groups`");

    while($groups = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getgroups)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $groups["group_name"] . "</td>";

        echo "<td><span style=\"background-color: red;\" class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["actual"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $groups["actual"] . " / " . $groups["needed"] . "</span></td>";

        // $diff = $groups["needed"] - $groups["actual"];
    //     echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">" . $diff . "</span></td>";
        echo "</tr>";   

    }
    echo "<tr><td><b>Total</b></td>";

        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";
        echo "<td><span class=\"badge\">0</span></td>";


        echo "</tr>";     


    ?>
```

I am just stuck on how to associate the needed and actual with the different months. The result i am after is shown in the mockup below

[image: Mockup]

Comment: How do you tell which numbers go where? Is id=1 for July and so on?

Comment: thats what i cant figure out, how to associate

Comment: Can you alter the DB? If so why not add column for date itself, like "Jul 2017" or "07-2017". With year added there you can keep old records and get statistics for previous needs and it's easy to add new row for every new month.